# Bad access when setting root view controller of navcontroller to self

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

I am getting *bad access error* when doing this. The third line throws the error. Why?

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Signup" bundle:nil];
AddFriendsTableViewController * svc =[sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addFriendsController"];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self];
```

Comment: Did it really say "bad access error?"  Worst, most uninformative error message ever.  Or did it really say something else?

Comment: yeah it just breakpoints infinitely on that

Comment: Have you checked your access/execute permissions yet?